# Django form not saving form entries

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to let users enter their own data to a form, but it is not being saved to my database and I can't figure out why.  I can add new form entries from the admin, so I'm not sure if I've written things one level too high or something?[test entry from admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXjO5.png)

I define my submission sheet in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime


class Submission(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    # TODO: night be multiple times, try to get working with one for now
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    collector_name = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    collector_equipment = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    sample_id = models.CharField(max_length=240)

    class Meta:
        # fields = ('project_name', 'location', 'time', 'weather', 'collector_name', 'sample_id')
        verbose_name_plural = 'submissions'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sample_id
```

and the form itself in forms.py is

```
from django import forms
from django_form_builder.forms import BaseDynamicForm
from .models import Submission

class SubmissionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Submission
        fields = (
            'project_name',
            'location',
            'time',
            'notes',
            'collector_name',
            'collector_equipment',
            'sample_id',
        )
        labels = {
            'project_name': 'Project Name',
            'location': 'Location',
            'time': 'Time',
            'notes': 'Notes',
            'collector_name': 'Collector Name',
            'collector_equipment': 'Collector Equipment',
            'sample_id': 'Sample ID',
        }
        help_texts = {
            'project_name': 'The project name',
            'location': 'Lat/long or comment',
            'time': 'Time (on/off) in UTC',
            'notes': 'Notes',
            'collector_name': 'Your name',
            'collector_equipment': 'Equipment used to collect the sample',
            'sample_id': 'Sample ID',
        }

    # def clean_form(self):
    #     SubmissionForm.Meta.
```

and I have made sure that I am saving the form in my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from .forms import SubmissionForm
from .models import Submission
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
from django.views import generic


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'forms/home.html')


def submit(request):
    form = SubmissionForm()
    return render(request, 'forms/submission_page.html', {'form': form})


def submission_success_view(request):
    return render(request, 'forms:success_page')


@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def create_submission(request):
    submission = get_object_or_404(Submission)
    # submission = form_detail(request, pk=pk)

    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == "POST":
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = SubmissionForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            submission = form.save()  ## TOTO: clean data
            # name_instance = form.cleaned_data
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("forms:success_page"), pk=submission.pk)
            # return redirect('form_detail', pk=submission.pk)
            # return render(request, 'success_page.html')

        # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
        else:
            form = SubmissionForm()
        return render(request, 'submission_form.html', {"form": form})


def form_detail(request):
    submission = Submission.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'forms/success_page.html', {'submission': submission})
```

the submission button brings me to the success page, but I don't think it is actually saving for some reason?

The submission page html is pretty simple:

```
<h1>Please enter your data</h1>
<form action="{% url 'forms:success_page' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {{form.errors}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Does your `forms:success_page` url point to the `create_submission` function?

Comment: No, it doesn't! I have fixed that, thanks so much! Now it is just reloading the form page after submission, but I think that's because I'm not entering in an acceptable time.

Comment: After commenting out the datetime field, I am still unable to get it to take the data from the page and save it to the database and the submission button is just returning me to the empty form page.

Comment: It was an issue with my urls.py. I needed a new one specifically to submit the form using create_submission even though there was no html page to go along with it!

Comment: You will normally handle the `GET` and `POST` method of the form within the same function. Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/ for more information.